# Linq to sql Distinct after join

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, linq

I have a join query and i want to filter the result of this query by using distinct. I want to get only one of the shoes which has same brand, model, primary color and secondary color. How can i make this ? Here is my join query.

```
var query = from b in db.BrandTbls.AsQueryable()
            join m in db.ShoeModelTbls on b.BrandID equals m.BrandID
            join s in db.ShoeTbls on m.ModelID equals s.ModelID
            join i in db.ShoeImageTbls on s.ShoeID equals i.ShoeID
            where s.Quantity > 0
            orderby m.ModelName
            select new 
            { 
                s.ShoeID, 
                m.ModelName, 
                m.Price, 
                b.BrandName, 
                i.ImagePath
            };
```

Comment: you can use group by having count>1

Comment: @Ganesh_Devlekar I don't know how can i adapt it to the linq to sql syntax.

Comment: So say 2 (or more) shoes have the same matching criteria, what do you want to do with it? I don't think you want `Distinct`, it sounds like you want to `GroupBy`.

Comment: @gunr2171 yes, you are right

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution. This query does approximately what i want to do

```
            var query = from b in db.BrandTbls.AsQueryable()
                    join m in db.ShoeModelTbls on b.BrandID equals m.BrandID
                    join s in db.ShoeTbls on m.ModelID equals s.ModelID
                    join i in db.ShoeImageTbls on s.ShoeID equals i.ShoeID
                    group new {b,m,s,i} by new {b.BrandName,m.ModelName,m.Price,s.ShoeID,s.PrimaryColor,s.SecondaryColor,i.ImagePath} into g
                    select new {g.Key.ShoeID,g.Key.BrandName,g.Key.ModelName,g.Key.ImagePath,g.Key.Price};
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove price from the output and use `Distinct()` like this:

```
var query = (from b in db.BrandTbls.AsQueryable()
            join m in db.ShoeModelTbls on b.BrandID equals m.BrandID
            join s in db.ShoeTbls on m.ModelID equals s.ModelID
            join i in db.ShoeImageTbls on s.ShoeID equals i.ShoeID
            where s.Quantity > 0
            orderby m.ModelName
            select new 
            { 
                s.ShoeID, 
                m.ModelName, 
                b.BrandName, 
                i.ImagePath
            }).Distinct();
```

Comment: Just a note: you still have `ShoeID` in there. Distinct won't work if every shoe has their own ID.

Comment: @gunr2171 Indeed, also the OP asks for primary colour and secondary colour which isn't included in the question.

Comment: I don't think it will work even if the ShoeID isn't there. He needs to implement an `IComparer`. After all, how is LINQ going to figure out if two objects are equal or not.

Comment: My idea is that it will simply invoke the default comparer to decide which objects are equal and then filter out duplicates. Now default comparer for Object isn't smart enough to check the fields that OP has mentioned, so he must write a simple comparer function for it.

Comment: Probably easier to use `GroupBy` as gunr mentioned.

Comment: How can i use GroupBy with linq to sql ?

Comment: @dotNET two anonymous objects with the same signature will use the same comparer for equality. You can test this by writing `Console.WriteLine(new { Test = 1 }.Equals(new { Test = 1 })); //True`

Comment: @dotNET LINQ *isn't* going to figure out if two objects are equal or not.  It is the query providers job to do that.  The LINQ `Distinct` is simply translated in to a SQL `Distinct`, and it doesn't care about how the type of the object defines equality when doing so.  The SQL Distinct will of course compare all of the fields in the query.

Comment: @Magnus See my previous comment.  As this isn't LINQ to objects, it's irrelivant.

Comment: @Servy: Since he's doing `Distinct()` AFTER creating anonymous objects through `SELECT()`, doesn't `Distinct()` run through LINQ-to-Objects instead of LINQ-to-SQL?

Comment: @dotNET No, it does not.